# How is Material determining position of input color?

Tags: design-patterns, colors, uicolor

https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors

How is Material determining **position** of input color? Can't seem to find a pattern based on lightness/darkness, luminance, hue...?

Any color theory experts out there?

Answer (score 0):

In the Material Design color picking tool that you have [linked](https://material.io/design/color/#tools-for-picking-colors), you choose the input color. The tool will generate an aesthetically-pleasing palette of colors that have lighter and darker tones that you can use as alternatives to your primary color in the GUI design. The tool then shows you the position of your selected color withing the range of tones presented in the palette.